# Displaying amount of downloads HTML

Tags: javascript, html, download

I have a repository on Github and I have several files that can be downloaded from it. Using EasyCounter, I managed to get the total amount of visits that page gets, but I would also like to know the amount of downloads for each file.

I would rather do this by some script in HTML than a 3-rd party website such as EasyCounter, but it's fine if I have to do that. Is there an easy way to do so?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

https://help.github.com/articles/getting-the-download-count-for-your-releases/

"To see how many times a file in a Release was downloaded, make a `GET` request to the [API for a single release](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-single-release). Within the JSON payload, every asset has a key called `download_count.`"

Using this API, you could build a web page that enumerates your releases, and displays the download count for each.